# Visual Studio Receiving Ethernet UDP (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, udp, ethernet, udpclient

I'm trying to receive UDP data over ethernet (from a controller) and running into some trouble. I know the controller is sending data because i can see it coming through on wireshark, but all the things I have tried haven't worked. The code below is the closest i've found to being able to receive the data i want. 
For more info: The controller IP and port are 192.168.82.27:1743, receiving IP and port on my end are 192.168.82.21:1740

```
    public class UDPListener
    {
        static UdpClient client = new UdpClient(1740);
        public static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                client.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(recv), null);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
            while (true)
            {

            }
        }
        //CallBack
        private static void recv(IAsyncResult res)
        {
            IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1743);
            byte[] received = client.EndReceive(res, ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
            //Process code
            Console.WriteLine(RemoteIpEndPoint + "  :  " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(received));
            client.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(recv), null);
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
public class Receiver
{
    private readonly UdpClient udp;
    private IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1740);
    public Receiver()
    {
        udp = new UdpClient
        {
            ExclusiveAddressUse = false
        };
        udp.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
        udp.Client.Bind(ip);
    }
    public void StartListening()
    {
        udp.BeginReceive(Receive, new object());
    }
    private void Receive(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        var bytes = udp.EndReceive(ar, ref ip);
        StartListening();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it seems to give me less than my posted code? Maybe i'm doing it wrong but the console gives me nothing from this (i added in a section to output whatever is received). When I run my initial posted code, the console outputs something like this: 192.168.82.247:1740  :  ? @??? which obviously isn't the data i'm looking for but it's something.